# How to read local Rails documentation with ri/rdoc tools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ri

I want to read documentation of gems in terminal. How can I do this with ri tools?
LinuxMint 18.3
Rails 5.1.4

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have the Docs on your system. They do not always install with a typical Rails installation.

You can download the doc for a specific gem with

`gem rdoc [gem-name] --no-rdoc`

The `--no-rdoc` tells it not to install the HTML version.

If you want the docs for all gems you have installed, you can use

`gem rdoc --all --ri --no-rdoc`

That may take a few minutes to download.

Once you have the docs downloaded, you can access them with

`ri -i`

This will give you an interactive prompt where you can search for gems or methods. You can even use tab to autocomplete.

Comment: Why my question has 'minus - status?'

Comment: I'm not sure. I suspect it was maybe because you were not very specific and your English was not very clear, but, I am just guessing. I think I understood what you were asking and I hope my answer helped.